# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy''

Tags: python-3.x

when I'm on a previous screen and I move to this screen, and I click on close presents this error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'destroy'
```

But when I run this screen directly, the close buttons work normally, I did some similar research but applying the resolutions I was unsuccessful, I am grateful for the help. Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *
import os


def fechar():
    tela_principal.destroy()


def tela_clientes():
    fechar()
    exec(open('cadastro_cliente.py').read(), {'c': tela_principal})


def tela_carros():
    pass


tela_principal = Tk()
tela_principal.title('Principal')
tela_principal.geometry('400x300+250+50')

fr_logo = Frame(tela_principal, borderwidth=1, relief='solid')
fr_logo.place(x=10, y=10, width=380, height=180)

btn_cliente = Button(
    tela_principal, text='CADASTRO\nCLIENTE', command=tela_clientes)
btn_cliente.place(x=30, y=220, width=100, height=50)

btn_carros = Button(tela_principal, text='PESQUISA\nCARROS',
                    command=tela_carros)
btn_carros.place(x=150, y=220, width=100, heigh=50)

btn_sair = Button(tela_principal, text='SAIR', command=fechar)
btn_sair.place(x=270, y=220, width=100, height=50)


tela_principal.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is in `'cadastro_cliente.py'`?

Comment: `def fechar():
      app.destroy() 
def gravar_dados():
        if tb_nome.get() != '':
            v_nome = tb_nome.get()
            v_telefone = tb_telefone.get()
            v_endereco = tb_endereco.get()
            v_email = tb_email.get()
            v_cpf = tb_cpf.get()
            v_carroCliente = tb_carroCliente.get()
            v_query = "INSERT INTO tb_clientes(T_NOME_CLIENTE,T_TELEFONE_CLIENTE,T_ENDERECO_CLIENTE,T_EMAIL_CLIENTE, T_CPF_CLIENTE, N_CARRO_CLIENTE) VALUES('"+ v_nome+"', '"+v_telefone+"', '"+v_endereco+"', '" + v_email+"', '"+v_cpf+"', '"+v_carroCliente+"')"`